How to set known categories for an org mode file?
I'm trying to set categories of TODO headings in a normally blank inbox.org file. I'd like to set a default set of categories so that when I use org-set-property I can select the category value from the prompted set.
Apparently (unless I'm missing something), using the typical PROPERTY_ALL syntax doesn't work for categories. In other words:
#+PROPERTY: CATEGORY_ALL Emacs Org

Doesn't work as I'd expect it to.

Yes, indeed: the algorithm implemented in org-property-get-allowed-values treats TODO, PRIORITY, CATEGORY, and all the members of the set org-special-properties specially. The _ALL mechanism does not apply to them.

You may be able to use org-property-allowed-value-functions to define your own treatment of CATEGORY. Alternatively, you can define your own org-property-get-allowed-values that does not treat the CATEGORY property specially.
